# Multiple unnamed parameters in Swift methods

Tags: function, swift, methods, parameters

As far as I can tell, Swift functions have unnamed parameters by default, but Swift methods do not (excluding the first parameter).  For example, given the following definitions:

```
func foo(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    return a + b
}

class MyClass {
    func bar(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
        return a + b
    }
}
```

I have to call `foo` with unnamed parameters:

```
foo(10, 20) // fine

foo(a: 10, 20) // error
foo(10, b: 20) // error
foo(a: 10, b: 20) // error
```

and I have to call `bar` with the first argument unnamed, and the second argument named:

```
MyClass().bar(10, b: 20) // fine

MyClass().bar(10, 20) // error
MyClass().bar(a: 10, b: 20) // error
MyClass().bar(a: 10, 20) // error
```

I understand that I can make any unnamed parameter named by using the `#` symbol, but my question is: **is there any way I can make both arguments to `bar` unnamed?**

In other words, **I would like to declare `bar` in such a way that I can call it like an ordinary function**:

```
MyClass().bar(10, 20)
```

Is this possible in Swift?  If so, how?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, you prefix the second parameter name with `_` to have it be anonymous:

```
class MyClass {
    func bar(a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
        return a + b
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: In Swift 4, you have to put '_' before the first argument also. 
    class MyClass {
      func bar(a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
        return a + b
      }
    }
    var g = MyClass()
    g.bar(3, 4)
        error: repl.swift:88:7: error: missing argument label 'a' in call